# R convert dates into Julian days in a loop

Tags: r, date, julian-date

I have some date for the year 1996 till 2014 that I need to convert into Julian days. Here is an example data:

```
date<- c("21-Jul", "14-Jul", "08-Jul", "08-Jul","16-Jul","22-Jul", "10-Jul", "02-Jul", "06-Jul","18-Jul","24-Jul", "15-Jul", "03-Jul", "04-Jul","19-Jul") 
year<-rep(1996:1998,each=5)
dat<-as.data.frame(cbind(date,year))
dat$date<-as.character(dat$date)
```

For each year, I want to convert date into Julian day i.e. day of the year. I used the following function from this link:

[Convert date without year into Julian day (number of days since start of the year)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656488/r-convert-date-without-year-into-julian-day?noredirect=1#40656865)

For leap-year (e.g. 1996), I can convert my date into Julian day as following:

```
julian(as.Date(paste0("1996-", ds$DS), format="%Y-%d-%b"), origin=as.Date("1996-01-01"))+1
```

For non-leap year (e.g. 1997), I can convert my date into Julian day as following:

```
julian(as.Date(paste0("1997-", ds$DS), format="%Y-%d-%b"), origin=as.Date("1997-01-01"))
```

Now, I want to do this in a loop for the period 1996 to 2014. I did this:

```
install.packages("lubridate") # function for detecting leap year
library("lubridate")
years <- 1996:2014
leap<-years[leap_year(years)]

for(i in 1996:2014){
 if(i %in% leap){
    julian(as.Date(paste0(i,"-", ds$DS), format="%Y-%d-%b"), origin=as.Date(i,"-01-01"))+1
} else {
   julian(as.Date(paste0(i,"-", ds$DS), format="%Y-%d-%b"), origin=as.Date(i,"-01-01"))
}}

Error in charToDate(x) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I think the error is happening because of `paste0(i,"-", ds$DS)` and this  `origin=as.Date(i,"-01-01"))`. Does anyone know how to address it?

Comment: Probably `origin=as.Date(paste0(i, "-01-01"))`?

Comment: Yes,  this works. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date without year into Julian day (number of days since start of the year)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656488/convert-date-without-year-into-julian-day-number-of-days-since-start-of-the-yea)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use the `POSIXlt` class which contains Julian days since start of the year as one of its components?

```
as.POSIXlt(as.Date(paste(dat$year, dat$date, sep = "-"),
        "%Y-%d-%b"))$yday
#[1] 202 195 189 189 197 202 190 182 186 198 204 195 183 184 199
```

Comment: Yes I can use it as well but I still need to separate out leap and now leap years and add `+1` in the end of the command for leap year?

Comment: You have for each date the year in your example data.frame. This answer handles leap years automatically. And if you need to add 1 I can't tell you. The documentation says `yday: 0–365: day of the year` Decide yourself if you rather prefer 1-366.